# OpenCart Admin Panel CSS not working

Tags: css, opencart, e-commerce, opencart2.3

I am using OpenCart v2.3.0.2 for my e-commerce web site. I have successfully completed all the steps to install OpenCart, but I see some CSS issues when I log in to the Admin panel.

[Here is the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA4Us.png)

Thanks for your helping

Comment: Any error in browser console?

Comment: No there isn't @MehravishTemkar